# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on The Great Outdoors breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6          9
Users destroyed                                  13          0
Users contacted                                  11          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue             4        443
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                3        150
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          5        449
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                3        212
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                14        676
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                6        779
Tags merged                                      17          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            16          0
Tag synonyms created                             17          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               15         25
Questions protected                               5         89
Questions migrated                                7          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0        121
Questions closed                                 29         82
Question flags handled⁴                          69         52
Posts unlocked                                    1          2
Posts undeleted                                   3         11
Posts locked                                      1         46
Posts deleted⁵                                  137        362
Posts bumped                                      0         21
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                                8          0
Comments flagged                                  1        913
Comments deleted⁶                             1,595      1,132
Comment flags handled                           645        269
Answers flagged                                  15        823
Answer flags handled                            356        482
All comments on a post moved to chat             19          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Across all the sites I mod, this one has by far the best percentage of flags handled by the community

Comment: @RoryAlsop, is that a good sign, (active members) or a bad sign (slow mods)?

Comment: I'd like to think an active community, based on the number of flags :-)